# Discord.py How to get previous track in a queue

Tags: discord.py

I created a discord.py music bot with lavalink
Now I want to send and Embed with the Informations about the previous song when you use the ,previous command

i think its very improvised with the lyrics function to get the Thumbnail but thats not the problem
I just want to ask how to replace the player.queue.current_track.title with something that says it have to use the informations of the previous title

```py
@commands.command(name="previous", aliases=["zurück"])
    async def previous_command(self, ctx, name: t.Optional[str]):
        player = self.get_player(ctx)
        name = name or player.queue.current_track.title

        async with ctx.typing():
            async with aiohttp.request("GET", LYRICS_URL + name, headers={}) as r:
                if not 200 <= r.status <= 299:
                    raise NoLyricsFound

                data = await r.json() 

                   

        if not player.queue.history:
            raise NoPreviousTracks

        player.queue.position -= 2
        await player.stop()
        embed = discord.Embed(
            title="Vorheriges Lied",
            colour=ctx.author.colour,
            timestamp=dt.datetime.utcnow(),
        )
        embed.set_thumbnail(url=data["thumbnail"]["genius"])
        embed.set_author(name=data["author"]),
        embed.set_footer(text=f"Angefordert von {ctx.author.display_name}", icon_url=ctx.author.avatar_url)
        await ctx.send(embed=embed)
```

Comment: i would suggest reading how [queues work](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/queue-in-python/)

Comment: Do you know any good tutorials or good explanations?

Comment: It's learning data structures I don't have experience in looking for this kind of video because I've learned it at school.